# Cleanup of [tree] and related tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

There's currently a lot of mistagging and overlap related to [tree](/questions/tagged/tree) (and [binary](/questions/tagged/binary)), [binary-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-tree) and [binary-search-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree).

**The goal:**

- [binary-search-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree) should be used to refer to questions *specific* to BSTs (not binary trees in general)
- [binary-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-tree) should be used to refer to non-BST binary trees.
- [tree](/questions/tagged/tree) should be used to refer to non-binary trees.
- [binary](/questions/tagged/binary) should not be used to refer to binary trees at all.

**My reasoning:**

- All BSTs are binary trees, so tagging a question with both [binary-search-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree) and [binary-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-tree) or [tree](/questions/tagged/tree) is redundant.
- Similarly, all binary trees are trees, thus using both [binary-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-tree) and [tree](/questions/tagged/tree) is redundant.
- [binary](/questions/tagged/binary) currently refers to binary numbers, it should not be used for binary trees as well.

**Useful searches:**

- [[binary] which refers to trees](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbinary%5D+tree+is%3Aquestion) x225
- [[tree] which refers to BSTs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btree%5D+%22binary+search%22) x343
- [[tree] which refers to binary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btree%5D+binary+-%22binary+search%22+is%3Aquestion) x538
- [[binary-tree] which refers to BSTs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbinary-tree%5D+%22binary+search%22) x599
- [[binary-tree] and [tree]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary-tree+tree) x219
- [[binary-search-tree] and [tree]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree+tree) x107
- [[binary-search-tree] and [binary-tree]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree+binary-tree) x160

(there's probably a bit of overlap in the above searches and they may not be 100% exact)

Not all of the questions in these results are necessarily bad - some questions may ask about both binary trees and trees in general, or about differences between the different types.

**Additional notes:**

Note that because the question is asking about a BST doesn't mean it's specific to a BST - finding the depth of a BST is the same as finding the depth of regular binary tree, thus [binary-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-tree) should be used there, not [binary-search-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree).

And there are plenty of questions that say binary tree (and probably many that are also tagged as such) but actually mean BST.

Ideally all questions tagged with [tree](/questions/tagged/tree), [binary-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-tree) and [binary-search-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree) should be reviewed.

There issue is likely to creep up again. It might be wise to put a note in each of the tag excerpts. And perhaps rename [tree](/questions/tagged/tree) (any suggestions?).

I've already done a fair amount of retagging with regard to this.

Comment: It's a valiant effort, but for little benefit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It might not be high on the list of things that needs to be done, but it's still on the list. [tag:binary] -> [tag:binary-tree] is probably the most significant part of this.